# If $\tan x =2$, then what are $\sin x$, $\cos x$, and $\cot x$?

Tags: trigonometry

How do you find $\sin x,\, \cos x,$ and $\cot x$, knowing that $\tan x=2$?

I tried doing it and I'm pretty sure that it's wrong because I only get decimals.

Comment: HINT: $x=\arctan2$. BTW, what do you mean "I only get decimals"???

Answer (score 3):

Build a right angle triangle with sides of length $2$, $1$ and $\sqrt{5}$. Then you can find all quantities from the definitions

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan x=2\iff\dfrac{\sin x}2=\dfrac{\cos x}1=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{2^2+1^2}}=?$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the identities $1 + tan^2(x)=sec^2(x)$, $1+cot^2(x)=cosec^2(x)$ and the definitions of the reciprocal trig functions.
This will give the answers up to an unknown sign, for which we need to known whether x is obtuse or acute.

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan x = 2 \Longrightarrow\sec x = \sqrt{5} \Longrightarrow \cos x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \Longrightarrow\sin x = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}},$$

assuming $0 \le x \le \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I got a different answer. for sinx I got 2√5/5

Comment: @happyglad $2\sqrt{5}/5=2/\sqrt{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

\begin{align*}
\cot x={}&\frac{1}{\tan x} \\
\sin(2x)={}&\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x} \\
\cos(2x)={}&\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}.
\end{align*}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/640688)

Comment: @MickG Knowledge of $\cos2x$ provides knowledge (up to the sign) of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$: $\cos^2x=(1+\cos2x)/2$ and $\sin^2x=(1-\cos2x)/2$